# ionic 2 search filter keep reloading page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working on an ionic 2 app where i need to apply a filter on a particular page. from my script what happens is, when i start typing it and starts filtering the page keeps on reloading back to its former state.

```
 getroutes() {
          this.http.post('http://localhost/app/get_products.php',{'trans_type':this.user_type_send}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data =>{
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            this.items= data;
        })

      }
      ngOnInit() {

        let loader = this.LoadingController.create({
          content: 'Please Wait'
          });
          loader.present().then(()=>{
           this.getroutes();
          loader.dismiss();
        })
      }

      filterItems(ev: any) {
        this.getroutes();
        let val = ev.target.value;

        if (val && val.trim() !== '') {
          this.items = this.items.filter(function(item) {
            return item.farm_name.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: Have any relation between  `this.seeds` and `this.items`?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, I’ve corrected the question

Comment: Your filter function looks fine. Can you show one item data in JSON?

Comment: {
            "farm_name": "Southbridge Towers",
            "latitude": 40.709206,
            "longitude": -74.003434
        },